# How to view the original URL of a file, which only causes a popup when clicked?

Tags: google-search

Foreword: I encountered this problem while trying to cite the Powerpoint [for my Economics SE question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/4622/4020).

> [image]

**Attempt 1:** I wish to determine the exact original URL of the Powerpoint discovered by Google [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22+the+total+quantity+does+not+change+after+the+tax+is+imposed%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=4uP3VKP-GYHBgwSUjYGoAQ#q=%22+the+total+quantity+does+not+change+after+the+tax+is+imposed%22).
As can be seen in screenshot above, the green URL displayed by Google is ellipsed and thus useless:

> eml.berkeley.edu/~burch/.../Tax%20Incidence%20day%203.

Where can I find the complete, unabriged URL without the ellipsis above?

**Attempt 2:** I right-clicked `Slides` (the title of the search result) > Copy Link Location.
Pasting produces this unnecessarily lengthy nonsense (I define  this as ***logorrhoea*** hereafter).

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Feml.berkeley.edu%2F~burch%2Fpubliceconconf2013%2FTax%2520Incidence%2520day%25203.ppt&ei=4uP3VLHMNbKBsQTrn4CwCw&usg=AFQjCNFM3VvRs0QOak7auYjGVihZKirobw&bvm=bv.87519884,d.cWc

**Attempt 3:** I right-clicked `Slides` > Open Link in New Tab. But then the URL remains the same ***logorrhoea*** as in Attempt 2. Also, immediately after the New Tab opens, a popup emerges demanding a choice: between opening the file in a selected program, or saving it. So this fails.

Comment: _"As you can see, the green URL displayed by Google is ellipsed and thus useless:"_ What green URL? When I click the link my browser immediately tries to download a PPT file. I'm not sure what you're looking for here. You have the URL to the file. What is it that you want?

Comment: @AlE. Sorry for any confusion. Please feel free to edit my OP. I want the original URL WITHOUT the ellipsis; Google only displays in green `eml.berkeley.edu/~burch/.../Tax%20Incidence%20day%203.` Does this answer your comment? Please advise.

Comment: That's the thing. *Where* are you seeing this green URL or this ellipsis?

Comment: @AlE. I've uploaded a screenshot above just now. Does this help? Please do write back if necessary.

Comment: Ah, Google Search. That clears some things up. What search string are you using?

Comment: @AlE. Delighted to hear that! I edited my OP again. Does that help? By `search string`, do you mean my search input?

Comment: I personally prefer using a Google Chrome extension or a user script (using Tampermonkey) that strips the tracking stuff from Google search results and replaces them with direct links. [Unidirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/undirect/dohbiijnjeiejifbgfdhfknogknkglio) is an example.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the green down arrow next to the green URL.  You will see "Cached" appear - click on that, and you will see the following:

[image]

As you can see, it displays the complete original URL of the file:

> http://eml.berkeley.edu/~burch/publiceconconf2013/Tax%20Incidence%20day%203.ppt